# First unique character in a string using LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, string, character, linkedhashmap

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return `-1`.

Examples:

```
s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode"
return 2.
```

In my solution I can find the character itself but I am looking to get the index of the character! How would I change my code to get the index using `LinkedHashMap`? And thank you in advance.

```java
public static void firstNonRepeatingString(String str) {
    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    for (char character : charArray) {
        if (lhm.get(character) == null) {
            lhm.put(character, 1);
        } else {
            lhm.put(character, lhm.get(character) + 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : lhm.entrySet())
        if (entry.getValue() == 1) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
}
```

```java
firstNonRepeatingString("aaabcccddeggf");
```

This will print `b`, but I want to print `3`.

Comment: [Java: method to get position of a match in a String?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2615749)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *`HashSet`*

The set is only used to avoid computing again a character that's already been seen. The set doesn't need to respect insertion order, as its goal is just check if an element exists. For that, `HashSet` is a proper option.

`StringUtils` has some good utils indeed, one of them is counting the occurrences of a single char/string within the source string.

As you want the first character which is unique, if the element didn't exist in the `set` and `countMatches` returns **1**, you got your result.

If no uniques are found, return **`-1`** *(for example)* as representation that no uniques were found in the string.

```
public static int firstNonRepeatingCharIndex(String str) 
{
   HashSet<Character> dupSet = new HashSet<>();   //duplicates list
   for(char c : str.toCharArray()) 
   {
      if (dupSet.contains(c))
          continue;
      if (StringUtils.countMatches(str, c) == 1)
          return str.indexOf(c);
      dupSet.add(c);
   }
   return -1;
}
```

This avoids:

- Useless iteration through all characters, after the result was found.
- Useless proccess of characters already seen.
- Useless map creation and its related operations, such as aggregations.

---

### *`HashSet + LinkedHashSet`*

For this specific problem, this shouldn't be required, but just in case you want to know which are the uniques and their order, so you want to iterate until the end, using two `Sets` could be an option.

```
public static int firstNonRepeatingCharIndex(String str) 
{
   LinkedHashSet<Character> lSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   HashSet<Character> dupSet = new HashSet<>();   //duplicates list

   for(char character : str.toCharArray()) 
   {
      if (dupSet.contains(character))  //exists in duplicates, continue
          continue;         
      if (lSet.contains(character))   //exists in the linkedSet, add to duplicates
          dupSet.add(character);          
      else
          lSet.add(character);        //first time seen, add to linkedSet
   } 

   lSet.removeAll(dupSet);          //remove all duplicates 
   if (lSet.isEmpty())
        return -1;

   return str.indexOf(lSet.iterator().next());  
}
```

---

### *`LinkedHashMap`*

*Only if the complete map is required, for getting stats, or whatever.*

Note there's no need to add/modify the entries. We directly set the number of occurrences if the key is not in the map.

```
public static int firstNonRepeatingCharIndex(String str) 
{
  LinkedHashMap <Character , Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  int c = 0, index = -1;
  for(char character : str.toCharArray()) 
  {
     if (lhm.get(character) == null)
     {
        int oc = StringUtils.countMatches(str,character);
        if (oc==1 && index<0)
           index = c;           //will only bet set once
        lhm.put(character, oc);
      }            
      if (index<0)     
        c++;                   //no need for this after index is found
   } 
   //showStatsOfMap(lhm); ?
   return index;
}
```

---

*If you don't need the map's result at all *(which makes you wonder why there's a map here)**

```
public static int firstNonRepeatingCharIndex(String str) 
{
   LinkedHashMap <Character , Integer> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   int c = 0;
   for(char character : str.toCharArray()) 
   {
      if (lhm.get(character)==null)
      {
          int oc = StringUtils.countMatches(str,character);
          if (oc == 1)
             return c;
          lhm.put(character, oc);
      }
       c++;
   }    
    //sendNonUniqueMap(lhm); //??? just to make use of it...
    return -1;
 }
```

Comment: @rzwitserloot Note that meta suggests to not downvote _good answers_ just because the question is in a bad shape. Answers should be judged based on their own quality only. See [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions). Take this as a note only though, I know that your main argument was that the answer did not contain any explanation, which is totally fair (aran edited it by now though).

Comment: @Zabuzard as a big part of the users here, I usually post the core answer and edit it afterwards, providing the context that seems useful. So I don't really believe this was related to the lack of context, as you can see 30 minutes after the edit.

Comment: @aran I am thinking or the `LinkedHashMap` answer, and I think it is possible to do it in one pass...

Comment: The hsahmap approaches just iterate through all, instead of returning, just for one reason: make use of the hashmap in some way. Because if not, there's no reason for it to exist....if you get 1, you could immediately return. Just added the last alternative

Comment: @aran I didn't see the code completely. You are doing basically the same I had in mind.

Comment: @hfontanez something like the last update would be "optimal", but again...only if you wish to have a map with the count of the letters..

Comment: @aran If you really wanna be clever, you can use Java 14  records `{character, firstIndex, count}` LOL

Comment: @hfontanez I must update myself...my testing jre is still 1.8. Amazed to know there's a java15 already... *Im getting old my friend..*

Comment: @aran I haven't played with records yet. But one of the idea of records is to create tuples for what I have heard.

Comment: @aran check out my post using a map and Java record.

Comment: Good answer! And, I agree with @Zabuzard

Answer (score 2):

My solution using a map of records.... Requires Java 14 or greater and enabling preview features.  Seems a little verbose, but basically what the code below does is walk through the array of characters in the inputted String and create a record `{character, index, count}`. Then, it puts the created record on the map. Since put returns the previous value of that key, the code then "merges" the two records and replaces the entry with a new record that keeps the character and lower index and increments the higher count by one.

Lastly, it uses a stream to filter all entries in the map to only those that have a count of 1 and then returns the entry with the lowest index.

When inputting "loveleetcode" the code prints out the entry with the lowest index that has a count of 1:

```
v=CharacterCount[character=v, index=2, count=1]
```

Keep in mind that the record doesn't really need the character (since the key is the character). All you need in the record is the lowest index for that character and the count.

---

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class FirstUniqueCharacterDemo {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
//      String input1 = "leetcode"; // return 0
        String input1 = "loveleetcode"; // return 2

        Map<Character, CharacterCount> charMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++) {
            
            char c = input1.charAt(i);

            CharacterCount current = new CharacterCount(c, i, 1); // records are immutable
            CharacterCount previous = charMap.put(c, current);
            if(previous != null) {
                current = current.merge(previous); // combine records (add 1 to count and keep lower index)
                charMap.replace(c, current);
            }
        }

        Entry<Character, CharacterCount> lowestIndex = charMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(recordsWithOneEntry -> recordsWithOneEntry.getValue().count() == 1)
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(CharacterCount::index))).orElse(null); // This will return either the CharacterCount record or null if none are found with a count of 1.
        
        System.out.println(lowestIndex);
        
    }

    public static record CharacterCount(char character, int index, int count) {
        public boolean isIndexGreater(int index) {
            return this.index > index;
        }
        
        public CharacterCount merge(CharacterCount cc) {
            int index = (isIndexGreater(cc.index()) ? cc.index : this.index);
            int count = this.count() > cc.count ? this.count() + 1 : cc.count() + 1;
            char c = this.character();
            return new CharacterCount(c, index, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: trully appreciated this input! Will save it in order to familiarize with these *new things*

Comment: @sammy if it was helpful, I will appreciate if you upvote it.

Comment: Fails for `input1 = "axxa";` with `NoSuchElementException`. Nevertheless, Your approach is very interesting.

Comment: An `orElse` instead of `get` will fix it.

Comment: @Kaplan good point! I forgot to test the edge case. Mind you, I did this around 3-4 AM with no sleep LOL

Comment: @Kaplan I just added `orElse(null)` to handle the edge case of no matching record found. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2):

*separate the characters in two groups existing once or multiple times*
*(we don't need to count the characters)*

`firstNonRepeatingChar( "aaabcccddeggf" );`
get the list `List<Integer> uniques` `[3, 9, 12]`
get the first element from `uniques` `3`

```
public int firstNonRepeatingChar( String s ) {
  List<Integer> uniques = IntStream.range( 0, s.length() ).boxed().collect(
    partitioningBy(i -> s.indexOf(s.charAt( i ),
      s.indexOf(s.charAt( i )) + 1) == -1)).get( true );  // [3, 9, 12]
  return( uniques.isEmpty() ? -1 : uniques.get( 0 ) );    // 3
}
```

*stopping with* `limit( 1 )` *after finding the character of interest*
*a further simplification that aran's tip picks up on*
this stream consists of only that one matching index, if there is any

```
public int firstNonRepeatingChar( String s ) {
  return( IntStream.range( 0, s.length() ).dropWhile( i -> s.indexOf(s.charAt( i ),
    s.indexOf(s.charAt( i )) + 1) > -1).limit( 1 ).findFirst().orElse( -1 ) );  // 3
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving this the proper attention. Still trying to get all the logic behind, but this is a pretty beautiful code.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 somewhat obvious options, that retains the spirit of using a `LinkedHashMap` :

1. you currently map the letter to the # of times it occurs. But that is not actually important; all you need to know is if the letter is unique (you don't need the count, you just need 'if I had the count, would it be 1?', which is considerably less information), and you need to know the position that it occurred at.

So why not map the character to the *position* instead of the count? Then, if you hit the same character again, you need to put something in the map to ensure you know it's no good (you can't remove it, because then a third occurrence would add it again, and would mean you give the wrong answer for input `aaabc`. Perhaps set it to -1 or some other value that means: This is not the answer you want).

2. Keep you code, but just loop through the string one more time, and find the index. Or just use String's `indexOf` method which does just that. This lets you turn e.g. the letter 'b' into the position in the string where the first 'b' occurs.

Comment: @aran Note that meta suggests giving hints instead of full answers for homework questions. See  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) (the "how to answer" part)

Comment: @Zabuzard thanks for it. I liked this part *Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines*. I will regret my downvote, as appreciation to you, not to this user

Comment: after re-reading this "comment/answer", my reason to downvote this time is clear. This answer is misleading and doesn't help OP in any way by following the linkedhashmap approach. It's much easier than this, which just offers a mess as solution. The point of all this is clear: *do not iterate through all elements,, do not compute every element independently.* The index can be retrieved while looping, why let it to the end of the execution? There's no point there. You're not doing OP a favour by giving him terribly bad alternatives. For a proper solution with the map, look  at my answer.

Comment: Is this not exactly what `StringUtils.countMatches` does? *It iterates through all elements*, to find out the total number of the character that is to be counted. *(Obviously after the count is 2 one can stop.)*

Comment: @Kaplan note that StringUtils.countMatches would only be executed once for each same character.  Also, as the question points to find the first one, once the method returns 1 the execution can end. Hello would need two, and in the extreme case of wwwwwwwwwwwwz , would only need two countMatches. There's a big difference there comparing to this approach. I guess the condition of finding the "first" is what somehow drives OP to the linkedHashMap solution. But this could be better achieved by using Sets, for example.

Comment: @aran Thanks. Of course, the following indices don't need to be considered here after the first matching one has been found.

Comment: @aran Apparently You misunderstood me. I overlooked the fact that I could make *my* solution simpler. Therefore the 1 to Your answer.

Comment: @Kaplan I totally mislead your point, my fault. To be sincere, i didn't even think you answered here, wasn't looking at this much. I must say, even if I don't understand completely the syntax `old school, must update myself` that i like very much the simplicity of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method, that *returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "leetcode";
    String str2 = "loveleetcode";
    String str3 = "aabbcc";

    String l1 = firstNonRepeatingString(str1);
    String l2 = firstNonRepeatingString(str2);
    String l3 = firstNonRepeatingString(str3);

    System.out.println(str1.indexOf(l1)); // 0
    System.out.println(str2.indexOf(l2)); // 2
    System.out.println(str3.indexOf(l3)); // -1
}
```

```java
public static String firstNonRepeatingString(String str) {
    return Arrays
            // split string into an array of
            // substrings, i.e. characters,
            // Stream<String>
            .stream(str.split(""))
            // collect to map and count the number of repetitions
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    s -> s, c -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new))
            // iterate over entry set of this map
            // Stream<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>
            .entrySet().stream()
            // filter letters without repetitions
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1)
            // take letter
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            // first one
            .findFirst()
            // or a null character if
            // there are no such letters
            .orElse("\u0000");
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Java streams: groupingBy and flatMapping keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358313/14940971)</sup>